# Python 3: TypeError: 'float' object is not callable

Tags: python, python-3.x, typeerror

**CONTEXT:**

I am writing a regression line calculator for my statistics class. To give you an idea of what it does you enter x and y values, enter the number of decimal points you want to round the numbers, prints the mean of x and y, standard deviation of x and y, r, r squared, b1, b0, the regression line equation, and the predicted and residual value for each x value. After that it will ask you if you want to add an x and y value to the table, remove the last two x and y values in the table, or insert an x value into the regression line.

**PROBLEM:**

What I am trying to do is update the regression line, predicted values, and the residual values once you add an x and y value into the table or remove the last two x and y values from the table. The problem is that it can successfully update the predicted values and the residual values, but whenever I try to update the value of the regression line equation, it gives me an error on line 219 saying:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "python", line 219, in 
>   TypeError: 'float' object is not callable

It works the first time it runs through since I make the values of the the x and y values the user puts as floats but since it's in a while loop, it runs it a second time and that's when the error happens. I don't know how to get rid of it.

**LINK:**

If you would like to see the code and try out the program, go to this link:
https://repl.it/@SomeRandomGuy/SmoggyHoarseBluefish

The relevant part of the code is

```
while(True):
    # ...

    # Gets the corelation coefficient (r)
    r = r(x, y, meanX, meanY, lenX)  # Raises a TypeError

    # ...
```

Comment: Please create a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Please read [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it) It should not be the responsibility of the answerer to edit the relevant part to your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Before* the first iteration of your main while loop, the name `r` refers to the function you've defined, which returns a `float`.

*During* the first iteration of that while loop, you call `r`:

```
r = r(x, y, meanX, meanY, lenX)
```

After this call, the name `r` refers to the `float` returned by the function `r`.

During the *second* iteration of that while loop, you attempt to call `r` again. But `r` is no longer a function, it's a `float`, which is not callable. Hence the error.

You can solve this by using a variable name in the while loop other than `r` to hold the correlation coefficient.

Comment: You're a genius and I am bad at coding. That's all I have to say.

Comment: Glad I could help!

Comment: Click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in. Here's more info: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Ah. Thanks. Did it.